# Ruby: Creating a drop down in Excel with a default value

Tags: ruby, excel

I need to create an Excel document in Ruby. My requirements are: multiple sheets, some basic formatting, ability to create hyperlinks between cells within the document and creating drop downs. I found two gems: axlsx and writeexcel which seem to offer almost everything that I want. The one mising thing is a default value for created drop downs. I ran the data validation examples for both gems and in both cases the cell containing the drop-down is empty until a human being chooses a value.

What I need is a default value displayed in the cell. So, if `%w[ maybe, yes, no ]` are the allowed values, then I want "maybe" to be displayed in the cell.

I read what seemed relevant parts of the documentation of both gems, but I didn't find any obvious way to say, that I want some value to be selected by default in the drop down.

I'm not emotionally attached to neither axlsx nor writeexcel, if you can suggest any other approach that will give me what I want, I'll be a happy camper.

Comment: There also a Roo gem, check out that it provides some data validation.

Comment: From http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/2.3.2 "Roo implements read access for all common spreadsheet types." It looks like Roo allows to read a spreadsheet. I need to write one.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've found a solution to my question with writeexcel gem. I'm not sure if it's stupid or if it's obvious, but it works well enough for me. What I did is write my default value to a cell, and then add a drop down to the same cell. Below is code based on [data_validate.rb](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel/blob/master/examples/data_validate.rb) example file:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

require 'writeexcel'

workbook  = WriteExcel.new('default_dropdown.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 32)
txt = 'Select a value from a drop down list'
worksheet.write(1, 1, 'open')
worksheet.write(1, 0, txt)
worksheet.data_validation(1, 1,
    {
        :validate        => 'list',
        :source          => ['open', 'high', 'close']
    })

workbook.close
```